# Why am I unable to move a player that extends image?

Tags: libgdx

I wanted to create a simple game where I will be able to move a player image horizontally. I am using Screens (at least trying to do so) and created the below:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private JumpingKitten jumpingKitten;
    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Player player;

public GameScreen(JumpingKitten jumpingKitten) {
    this.jumpingKitten = jumpingKitten;
    this.createCamera();
    this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(1026.0f, 768.0f, this.camera));
    this.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    initPlayer();
}

private void initPlayer() {
    player = new Player();
    stage.addActor(player);
    stage.act();
}

private void createCamera() {
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    this.camera.setToOrtho(false, 1026.0f, 768.0f);
    this.camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    this.clearScreen();
    handleInput();
    this.camera.update();
    this.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(this.camera.combined);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    spriteBatch.end();
}

private void clearScreen() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.15F, 0.15F, 0.3F, 1.0F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(16384);
}

private void handleInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
        player.STARTING_X -= 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // STARTING X incorrect
        System.out.println("A is pressed"); // shown in console
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
        player.STARTING_X += 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
}
```

And below is the player class:

```
public class Player extends Image {

private static final int PLAYER_WIDTH = 119;
private static final int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 136;

public static int STARTING_X = 100;
public static final int STARTING_Y = 100;


public Player() {
    super(new Texture("Cat_Idle_1.png"));

    this.setOrigin(100, 100);
    this.setSize(PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);

    this.setPosition(STARTING_X, STARTING_Y);

}
```

Even though I have completed some simple tutorials, I am unable to retrieve the x coordinate of the player object. This is stopping me from translating the player object along the x axis. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong, here? I honestly think that I jumped into something I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `STARTING_X` and `STARTING_Y` is just the *start* position of the object, not the objects actual position. To change the objects position use `player.setPosition(x, y)` or the `setX(x)` and `setY(y)` methods. To retrieve the current position of your player you use the `getX()` and `getY()` methods.

So your `handleInput` would look like this:

```
private void handleInput() {
    float moveAmount = 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
        // Same as your player.x -= moveAmount, but correct this time.
        player.setX(player.getX() - moveAmount);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
        player.setX(player.getX() + moveAmount);
    }
}
```

---

Some other comments:

- You don't need to create a new `SpriteBatch`. Your stage has its own internal `SpriteBatch` already.
- You don't need to create a new `OrthographicCamera`. Your `Viewport` has its own internal `Camera` already.
- When you use a `Viewport` you need to make sure to call `viewport.apply()` and `viewport.update(width, height)`.
- You **need** to call stage.act() in your render method as well as stage.draw().

With this in mind your code should be something like this (only edited parts included):

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    // These two are not needed.
    // private OrthographicCamera camera;
    // private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


public GameScreen(JumpingKitten jumpingKitten) {
    ...
    // No need to create a new camera for the viewport.
    this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(1026.0f, 768.0f));
}

private void initPlayer() {
    ...
    // No need to call stage.act() here.
    // stage.act();
}

// We don't need to create a new Camera.
//private void createCamera() {
//    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
//    this.camera.setToOrtho(false, 1026.0f, 768.0f);
//    this.camera.update();
//}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ...

    // Instead of camera.update() we call viewport.apply().
    // We don't need to manually set projection matrix, stage does this internally.
    // this.camera.update();
    // this.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(this.camera.combined);
    stage.getViewport().apply();

    // Stage uses internal batch and uses begin() and end() internally.
    // spriteBatch.begin();
    stage.act(); // <- Don't forget this! You need to update your stage every frame.
    stage.draw();
    // spriteBatch.end();
}

//We need this method to update the viewport dimensions!
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Your instructions have helped me a lot sir. Player character is now moving as needed. Any chance you could advise a book/tutorial I could follow that describes these things in more detail? Kind regards, Pawel

Comment: @Paweł You should take a look at the [official wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki). It also helps to take a look at the documentation and source which you should be able to do in your IDE (if you're using eclipse just CTRL+L.Mouse to get to the source.